# How to Google OAuth2 to upload videos to 2 different YouTube account with a Python script

Tags: python, youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-oauth

I have a Python script that uploads videos to my YouTube channel.

Now I have more than one YouTube channel under my account and want to upload to the second channel once I'm done with the first. But OAuth 2 at no point asks me which account I want to upload to, and keeps uploading to the first channel that I authorised.

How should I fix this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Post the code you write to upload videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an access token for each account. There are various ways you can get them, for example request offline access for each account and store the two refresh tokens. There are other ways too. You'll need to detail the behaviour you want to achieve.